# Why doesnt bitmapImage in Image refresh?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I am trying to create a simple coin toss game. I am trying to create "spin the coin" effect. I have two `BitmapImage`s which shows coin from little different angle. I have `for` loop and try to change `BitmapImage` from `Image`. This however doesn't work for some reason, it just skips coinflip and shows results. If I put `MessageBox` between each imagechange, it works. Why?

```
public void spinCoin()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                imageBox.Source = side1;
                imageBox.Source = side2;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Whole code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/cS3vZhKN http://pastebin.com/7xNsLgWC

EDIT: 
Working code:

```
public async void spinCoin()
    {
        label.Content = "Heitetään...";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            imageBox.Source = side1;
            await Task.Delay(50);
            imageBox.Source = side2;
            await Task.Delay(50);


        }

    }
```

-

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        spinCoin();
        await Task.Delay(600);
        if (tossCoin() == 1)
        {
            imageBox.Source = kr;
            label.Content = "Kruuna!";
        }
        else
        {
            imageBox.Source = kl;
            label.Content = "Klaava!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this must be executing on the UI thread, the UI never gets a chance to update before the method exits. Even if this was executing in parallel with the UI thread, it would go way too fast for the UI to properly display the animation.

You need a timer mechanism to pace the updates and have it run on a background thread. Alternatively, you could make the method async and insert `await Task.Delays` between each assignment of the image source.

Comment: So basically I need to create a new thread on which I will start the timer. When the timer has run X milliseconds it changes the image. Am I on the right track?

Comment: That's about the most complicated way to do it though. You could use a DispatcherTimer or use async-await with Task.Delays in your original method.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I managed to get it working with async `await Task.Delay`